# What is the average volume of the human Psychic tear? ("emotional tear")

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, human-eye

My goal is to find out the volume of the average human "emotional tear" (Psychic tear - sadness, happiness), specifically when crying. I found a lot of information about Basal tears (constant lubrication), as well as Reflex tears (when slicing onions), but nothing about the volume of Psychic tears.

I should mention that in a 2016 study *Is it possible to cry a river* by the University of Leicester, the volume of one average tear that was used is the same as the volume of the average Basal tear - 6.2 micro liters. (Volume of Basal tears was also determined to be 6.2 micro liters in another study I found online)

I have a slight doubt that the average Psychic tear has the same volume as the average Basal tear, which is approximately 6.2  micro liters plus/minus 2 micro liters.

Could it be that both types of tears have the same average volume, and it is only the flow intensity that is different?

There seems to be nothing about this online after several hours of research. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the volume of a single tear drop or the total volume of the 'available' tear?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the volume of the average tear drop.